# Create user with password and without ssh key on redhat

Tags: linux, ssh, redhat-enterprise-linux, amazon-web-services, pam

I have a very simple question, I have created an instance with aws AMI. I can log into it using my key. But I want to login using a username and password.

```
useradd username -p password
```

This has created the user and password, but when I try to login I get

```
ssh username@10.250.32.240
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I am on redhat

```
cat /etc/*release
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2018.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03
```

I did some reading and learnt it must be something to do with pam but I failed adding/removing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Modify `/etc/sshd_config` and set the `PasswordAuthentication` setting to `yes`.

Then restart sshd: `/etc/init.d/sshd restart`.

You'll either need to sudo to root, or use `sudo` to run these commands.